# How do I Get Plain Text Beside an HTML Element using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, dom

```
<span>
    <label for="305">
        <input type="checkbox" name="305" style="vertical-align: middle;" value="305" id="305"> Farming General
    </label>
</span>
```

How do I get text "**Farming General**" using jQuery. Please do not ask me to change HTML structure

Comment: You should change the markup regardless, as an `id` starting with a number is invalid and will cause odd problems.

Comment: @bobince - It's worth noting since we're seeing it more now that the rule applies to HTML4 and not 5...last I read they only have to be unique in HTML5.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can grab it using an ID selector, going to the [`.parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) and using [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) like this:

```
​$("#305").parent().text()
//or:
$("label[for='305']").text();
```

Though, IDs starting with a number aren't valid until HTML5, just be aware :)

---

You can also get it without jQuery, like this:

```
document.getElementById("305").nextSibling.nodeValue
```

Though you may want to trim it down with [`$.trim()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/), like this:

```
$.trim(document.getElementById("305").nextSibling.nodeValue)
```

Comment: ​$("#305").parent().text() This is more feasible to my current function thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest I think.

`$("label[for='305']").text();`